# Using a search button to carry out a search of the text in the edit text field

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and i use android studio. i am trying to create a search app like google, so when i type a word in the edit text bar and click the search button, a search is carried out and the result is displayed from search engines like google scholar.com or elvesier.com. i have already tried this and i have created the UI, so i need if a search is typed in the search bar and the send button is clicked, the search is carried out from sites like google scholars or refseek.com and displayed.

```
LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="197dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher1"
            android:layout_weight="0.12" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="291dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_message"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:imeOptions="actionSend" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/button_message"
                />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you have not mentioned the issue that you are facing !!!! just told what you have done....

Comment: i have created the UI, using the code i pasted, so i need if a search is typed in the search bar and the send button is clicked, the search is carried out from sites like google scholars or refseek.com and displayed, how do i go about that